# create download links for any file type JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page where some files are stored.
These files can vary between `.pdf`, `.csv`, `.jpg`, `.doc`, `.png`, `.xlsx`.
I want a download button for each file that downloads the file directly.
I also want to give them a custom name when it gets downloaded.
I'm using a `PHP` script to loop through my saved files.
I'm saving a random name and the original name inside the database for each file.
[image]
I want to download each file using the original name of the file and not the random name.
I tried using this script I found on stack to download the file and rename it.

```
function downloadfile(url, name) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = name;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

But this seems not to work for `.csv`or `.pdf` type files.
When I click a link that should download a `.pdf` file, It opens the file in the browser instead.
Also for other file types it doesn't rename at all.
Is there a function in `JS` that downloads every file extension with a custom name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in PHP by [setting the `Content-Disposition` header](https://www.lifewire.com/using-php-to-force-download-3469180):

```php
<?php

$mimeType = mime_content_type($fileName);

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$originalName");
header("Content-type: $mimeType");
readfile($fileName);
```

Note: I added the dynamically generated mime type using [mime_content_type()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) to the linked example.

Then link the download button to this script and pass it the specific file it should download, and then set the `$fileName` and `$originalName` variables.

```
<a href="downloadFile.php?file=1">Download</a>
```

And in the script (pseudo code):

```php
$row = // select * from files where id = $_GET['id']
// or 
$row = // select * from files where name = $_GET['name']

// add your column names
$fileName = $row->fileName;
$originalName = $row->originalName;
```

Comment: can you write how to trigger the download? I'm now using `$.ajax` but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: It can be just a normal link with `target="blank"`. A new browser tab/window should open and automatically close once the download starts.

Comment: But I need to post the filename and originalname to that page? how does the page know what values

Comment: Yes, you need to post something that can uniquely identify the row in your database. That could for example be an ID or the original name. I've updated my answer.

Comment: When I download it. the document or file is empty